# how can i get the number of items in a foreach jstl tag?

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have the following code under javascript `<script></script>`:

```
<c:forEach items="${lifeEvents}" var="event" varStatus="loop">
        latitudes["${loop.index}"] = <c:out value="${event.place.location.latitude}"/>;
        longitudes["${loop.index}"] = <c:out value="${event.place.location.longitude}"/>;
        lastEvent = "${loop.index}";
        if("${loop.index}" > 0)
            waypointEvents["${loop.index}"] = new google.maps.LatLng(latitudes["${loop.index}"],longitudes["${loop.index}"]);
</c:forEach>
```

How can i know the exact number of LifeEvents that exist in the lifeEvents list?  prior to running the entire loop untill the end ofc

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your lifeEvents is a collection, then you can get the size of the collection using jstl **fn:length**

```
<c:out value="${fn:length(lifeEvents)}" /> <%-- size of liveEvents --%>
```

Make sure you have added the following taglib at the top of your page to allow the fn namespace.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
```